# How to stop xsbt from reloading webapp on resources change

Tags: sbt, lift, xsbt-web-plugin

We are using `sbt` with `xsbt-web-plugin` to develop our liftweb app. In our project build we have several subprojects and we use `dependencies` of a `Project` to share some stuff between all the subprojects.

```scala
object ProjectBuild extends Build {
//...

lazy val standalone = Project(
  id = "standalone",
  base = file("standalone"),
  settings = Seq(...),
  dependencies = Seq(core) // please notice this
)

lazy val core = Project(
  id = "core",
  base = file("core"),
  settings = Seq(...)
}
// ...
}
```

To ease the development we use `'project standalone' '~;container:start; container:reload /'` command automatically recompile changed files.

We decided to serve some common assets from shared `core` project as well. This works fine with lift. But what we faced when added our files to `core/src/main/resources/toserve` folder, is that any change to any javascript or css file causes application to restart jetty. This is annoying since such reload takes lots of resources.

So I started investigating on how to prevent this, even found someone mentioning `watchSources` sbt task that scans for changed files.

But adding this code as a `watchSources` modification (event that `println` prints all the files) does not prevent from reloading webapp each time I change assets located in `core` `resources` folder.

```scala
lazy val core = Project(
  id = "core",
  base = file("core"),
  settings = Seq(
    // ...
    // here I added some tuning of watchSources
    watchSources ~= { (ws: Seq[File]) => ws filterNot { path =>
      println(path.getAbsolutePath)
      path.getAbsolutePath.endsWith(".js")
    } }
 )
```

I also tried adding `excludeFilter` to `unmanagedSorces`, `unmanagedResorces` but with no luck.

I'm not an sbt expert and such modification of settings looks more like a magic for me (rather then a usual code). Also such tuning seem to be uncovered by documentation =( 
Can anyone please help me to prevent sbt from reloading webapp on each asset file change?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track by using `watchSources`, but you'll also need to exclude the *resources* directory itself:

```
watchSources ~= { (ws: Seq[File]) =>
  ws filterNot { path =>
    path.getName.endsWith(".js") || path.getName == ("resources")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not help =( Liftweb app still reloads if I edit and save some js file in `core`.

Comment: Where specifically is the *.js* file?  Is it in *core/src/main/resources*?

Comment: File is stored in `/core/src/main/resources/toserve/core/js/`, but any file being edited from `/core/src/main/resources/` causes the same behaviour.

Comment: You might need to reuse the `watchSources` filter above in your root project as well.  Do you see the same problem when you perform a triggered execution on only the *core* subproject?

Comment: `core` itself does not have container configuration. So doing `'project core' '~;container:start; container:reload /'` does not work (`No such setting/task container:start`). I tried adding same `watchSources` to `standalone` app configuration in `ProjectBuild`, but with no luck (editing any file from core resources folder still causes app reload).

Comment: Hi, James! I created a test use-case for you to experiment.  https://yadi.sk/d/NNgWowTnbchbK

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch from using "resources" folder to using "webapp" folder? That will also free you from restarts. Here's a demo project for Lift (that uses "webapp"):

https://github.com/lift/lift_26_sbt/

For example, the "basic" template:

https://github.com/lift/lift_26_sbt/tree/master/scala_211/lift_basic/src/main/webapp

Comment: BTW, sorry for the late answer. The official suppor channel is the mailing list, although I personally try to watch stackoverflow, too. (Had my RSS client broken for 2 weeks).

Comment: This seem not to have any projects where a subproject uses another subproject as a dependency. There is no way to use webapp contents from inside `core` in my example.